# open serial port and wait for modbus request: good implementation?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, serial-port, modbus

i am fairly new to nodejs and am a bit stuck with the following: i have a module (modbuslistener below) that opens a serial port and waits for modbus data (basically a couple bytes starting with a certain slave address). when the data is correct (crc matches) the process (main) should end successfully and this works.

not entirely sure about the: return p.then(v => {})
but seems to work

now what i want to do is throw an exception when no data (the timeout does stop the process) or incorrect data. i cannot seem to throw and exception to the main routine? (adding a reject means i need to catch it but then?)

any help much appreciated!

(also if the code below can be better... please!)

thanks
frank

modbuslistener:

```
const serial = require('serialport')
const interbytetimeoutparser = require('@serialport/parser-inter-byte-timeout')
const crc = require('crc')

module.exports = async function(device) {

  const port = await new serial(device)

  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

     setTimeout(function() {
       console.log('time is up!')
       resolve()
     }, 30000)

     const parser = port.pipe(new interbytetimeoutparser({
        interval: 30
  }))

  parser.on('data', function(data) {

     // message for us?
     if (data[0] === config.mb.serverid) {

       // correct message?
       if (crc.crc16modbus(data) === 0) {

         console.log('function: ' + data[1])
         console.log('address: ' + (data[2] * 256 + data[3]))
         console.log('value: ' + (data[4] * 256 + data[5]))

         port.close()

         resolve()

       } else {

         console.log('got corrupted data')
       }
     }
   })

 })

 return p.then(v => {})
}
```

main:

```
const modbuslistener = require('./edge/modbuslistener')

 (async function() {

   await modbuslistener('/dev/tty.usbserial-AD0JM65Z')

   log('done')

   process.exit(0)
 })()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your `Promise` object with a [catch-closure/function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch), then exceptions `throw`n will be caught and handled by that closure/function.

Having said that, while not using a reject-closure to capture error states?

Comment: actually want to throw a java-like exception (or not catch it) in this part so errors can be dealt with at a higher level. seems it does not allow to reject without catching it at the lower level?